# Windows 7 Task Scheduler to start application in user session

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

When adding a new scheduled task, the application being launched will run in session 0, which means that the windows won't display. Is there any way to let Task Scheduler start the process in the user session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you want to run your task in interactive mode.

[/IT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736357%28VS.85%29.aspx): A value that enables the task to run interactively only if the /RU user is currently logged on at the time the task runs. The task runs only if the user is logged on.

It appears this option can only be set from the schtasks utility and not from the task scheduler.